# Is there any fix/update for log4j vulnerability for Karate framework?

Tags: log4j, karate

Is it safe to use log4j with karate latest version 1.1.0?
Will the log4j vulnerabilities affect the framework? Is there any way to update log4j version to 2.17.0 in the mix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate does not use log4j and uses logback instead. Maybe you are using an old version, so you need to upgrade.

Note that even logback had a vulnerability so you should use Karate 1.2.0.RC2, please find details here: https://twitter.com/getkarate/status/1471710785051103233

Comment: That helps. Thanks for the clarification.